# How to read and update full HTML string as varialbe using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a JSON object which contains the HTML as a string and the array of an element with an ID and that values to be updated. *`(i.e ID= Source, Value= Destination)`*

```
var myDynamicJSON = {
        "Variables": [{
                "Source": "txtCustomerName",
                "Destination": "Chintan Khetiya"
            },
            {
                "Source": "txtInvoiceDate",
                "Destination": "6/21/2021, 3:29:01 PM"
            }
        ],
        "invoiceEmail": "<!doctype html><html> <head> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> <title>Email</title> <style> .emailBody { width: 100%; } .messageBodyUserNameFont { margin: 0; font-size: 18px; color: rgb(255, 140, 0); padding: 10px 0 10px 0; display: inline; } .messageBodyTextFont { margin: 0; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(50, 50, 50); line-height: 1.5; display: inline; } </style> </head> <body class="emailBody"> <p id="txtCustomerName" class="messageBodyUserNameFont">,</p> <p id="txtInvoiceDate" class="messageBodyTextFont"></p> </body></html>"
    }
```

I have created a function to read the `myDynamicJSON`  variable which executes the loop to find and updates the element values by source and destination JSON object.

```
for (var i in myDynamicJSON.Variables.length) {
        var item = myDynamicJSON.Variables.[i];
        document.getElementById(item.Source).innerHTML = item.Destination;
    }
```

Now, How can I update the same string object of JSON as full HTML.

I tried

```
myDynamicJSON.Variables = myDynamicJSON.Variables.getElementById(item.Source).innerHTML = item.Destination;
```

(inside the loop) but it doesn't give me the updated HTML variable

My expected output: (Updated the JSON string with array values)

```
"invoiceEmail": "<!doctype html><html> <head> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> <title>Email</title> <style> .emailBody { width: 100%; } .messageBodyUserNameFont { margin: 0; font-size: 18px; color: rgb(255, 140, 0); padding: 10px 0 10px 0; display: inline; } .messageBodyTextFont { margin: 0; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(50, 50, 50); line-height: 1.5; display: inline; } </style> </head> <body class="emailBody"> <p id="txtCustomerName" class="messageBodyUserNameFont">**Chintan Khetiya**</p> <p id="txtInvoiceDate" class="messageBodyTextFont">**6/21/2021, 3:29:01 PM**</p> </body></html>"
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Is it at all possible this is being caused by the typo in your `item` variable. 

 `var item = myDynamicJSON.Variables.[i]`
should be
 `var item = myDynamicJSON.Variables[i]`

Comment: Too much JSON where it doesn't exist. `for (var i in myDynamicJSON.Variables.length)` doesn't make sense, `.length` is a number, use a regular `for` loop instead of `for .. in`, or rather just `forEach` to iterate an array.

Comment: @RossMoody No, I am getting `1tem.Source` and `item.Destination` but I have a query that how can I get the same update HTML variable string.
This is simple JSON, It might a very long with bulky HTML and Variables array.

Comment: @Teemu Yes, generally I do use `$.each()` here I just shared for a simple case statement. I will definitely replace that. Thank you!

Comment: Apart from the loop, `.invoiceEmail` is just a string, there's no querable elements in a string. It looks like you'd need an entire document as text, you can create a [DOMImplementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation) object, change it and then convert it to text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note you have too many /body /html tags

NOTE: I changed the `<body class="emailBody">` to `<div class="emailBody">`

We could use a DOMParser as suggested by @VLAZ

```js
var myDynamicJSON = {
  "Variables": [{
      "Source": "txtCustomerName",
      "Destination": "Chintan Khetiya"
    },
    {
      "Source": "txtInvoiceDate",
      "Destination": "6/21/2021, 3:29:01 PM"
    }
  ],
  "invoiceEmail": "<!doctype html><html> <head> <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width\" /> <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" /> <title>Email</title> <style> .emailBody { width: 100%; } .messageBodyUserNameFont { margin: 0; font-size: 18px; color: rgb(255, 140, 0); padding: 10px 0 10px 0; display: inline; } .messageBodyTextFont { margin: 0; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(50, 50, 50); line-height: 1.5; display: inline; } </style> </head> <body class=\"emailBody\"> <p id=\"txtCustomerName\" class=\"messageBodyUserNameFont\">,</p> <p id=\"txtInvoiceDate\" class=\"messageBodyTextFont\"></p> </body></html>"
}

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(myDynamicJSON.invoiceEmail, "text/html")

myDynamicJSON.Variables.forEach(vari => doc.querySelector("#"+vari.Source).textContent = vari.Destination)
console.log(doc.documentElement )
```

or a  [DOMImplementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation) as suggested by @Teemu

```js
var myDynamicJSON = {
  "Variables": [{
      "Source": "txtCustomerName",
      "Destination": "Chintan Khetiya"
    },
    {
      "Source": "txtInvoiceDate",
      "Destination": "6/21/2021, 3:29:01 PM"
    }
  ],
  "invoiceEmail": "<!doctype html><html> <head> <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width\" /> <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" /> <title>Email</title> <style> .emailBody { width: 100%; } .messageBodyUserNameFont { margin: 0; font-size: 18px; color: rgb(255, 140, 0); padding: 10px 0 10px 0; display: inline; } .messageBodyTextFont { margin: 0; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(50, 50, 50); line-height: 1.5; display: inline; } </style> </head> <body><div class=\"emailBody\"> <p id=\"txtCustomerName\" class=\"messageBodyUserNameFont\">,</p> <p id=\"txtInvoiceDate\" class=\"messageBodyTextFont\"></p></div> </body></html></body></html>"
}

let HTML = myDynamicJSON.invoiceEmail;
let doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("Email");
let head = doc.querySelector("head");
head.innerHTML = HTML.match(/<head>(.*?)<\/head>/)[1]
let body = doc.querySelector("body");
body.innerHTML = HTML.match(/<body>(.*?)<\/body>/)[1]

myDynamicJSON.Variables.forEach(vari => body.querySelector("#"+vari.Source).textContent = vari.Destination)
console.log(doc.documentElement)
```